# Android Java app Crash on start (out-of-order static field indexes 65535 and 0)

Tags: java, android, xml, dex

i have problem in my Android project , my project is very big and have many methods so recently i tried to add an TextView in my XMl file and it work , but when i try to add ID for the TextView my app crash , so i changed the ID of my TextView , but its still crash , and when i delete the id of TextView my app work ,

then i read the logCat :

```
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat, PID: 13213
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /data/downloads, /data/priv-downloads]]
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:802)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5392)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6138)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /data/downloads, /data/priv-downloads]]
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1022)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:796)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 9 more
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat-1/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat-1/base.apk': out-of-order static field indexes 65535 and 0
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:367)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:112)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:77)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:359)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeElements(DexPathList.java:323)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:263)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:126)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:58)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:520)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:553)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1869)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:766)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ContextImpl.<init>(ContextImpl.java:2057)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2002)
11-16 21:26:33.269 13213 13213 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5298)
```

i googled to find any solution , so i found some answers talking about adding

```
multiDexEnabled true;
```

https://ranjithexpertisers.medium.com/unable-to-instantiate-application-android-support-multidex-multidexapplication-2b09a31d10a

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'bhrivchat'
            keyPassword '123456a@'
            storeFile file('../bhrivchat.jks')
            storePassword '123456a@'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
         multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        
            
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            //multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
    
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    
    

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.ComputerScience"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        
        <activity
            android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.ui.LoginActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyThemeNoActionbar"/>
            
            <activity
                android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.Home"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.ui.RegisterActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyThemeNoActionbar"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.ui.AddGroupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MyThemeNoActionbar"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.ui.AddPost"
            />
        <activity
            android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.ui.AddBook"
            />
        <activity
            android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.ui.addVideo"
            android:theme="@style/MyThemeNoActionbar"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.ui.AddSound"
            />
        <activity
            android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.ui.CommentActivity"
            />
        <activity
            android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.ui.ImageViewerActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Translucent"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.ui.DecoderActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MyThemeNoActionbar"/>
        
        <receiver android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.MyReciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.service.ServiceNotif"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <service
            android:name="com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat.service.FriendChatService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:persistent="true"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My Application Class

```
package com.wanjy.dannie.rivchat;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
//import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

public class ComputerScience extends Application {
    // Called when the application is starting, before any other application objects have been created.
    // Overriding this method is totally optional!
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Required initialization logic here!
    }

    // Called by the system when the device configuration changes while your component is running.
    // Overriding this method is totally optional!
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    // This is called when the overall system is running low on memory, 
    // and would like actively running processes to tighten their belts.
    // Overriding this method is totally optional!
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

so i tried this solution , but my app still crash so what is the problem ? , and how can i fix this ?

Comment: have you added multiDexEnabled in your build.gradle file?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what IDE are you using? Are you on AndroidX or Support Libraries?

Comment: @PrinceAli    i modified my question

Comment: @AkashRaghav i modified my question

Answer (score 0):

If you have Application class implemented in your code(if not create it). Extend it with MultiDexApplication.

```
MyApplicationClass extends MultiDexApplication
```

and add the name of your application class in manifest application tag -

```
android:name="your.package.name.MyApplicationClass"
```

Comment: i did this already but it still crash , i Refreshed my project but nothing.

Comment: post your manifest, build.gradle and Application class code